# Adding alt text to a Tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, accessibility

I've been working to make my lecture notes as accessible as possible and I've moved onto my trig class (and I'm still a bit of a LaTeX novice). However, I'm running into some issues as I know how to add alt text to images and such but not to graphs created using the Tikz package. So, my question is, is there a way to add alt text to something simple like the code below?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);
    \fill[black] (origo) circle (0.05);
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(3,0) node(mary)[black,right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,3) node[black,right] {$y$};
    \draw[thick] (origo) -- ++(45:3) coordinate (bob);
    \fill (bob) circle (0.05);
    \node[] at (1.2,1.5){r};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

So that when a screen reader encounters this it reads something like "The picture is of a plane, with a point at.... and a line reassuring...."

Comment: Welcome. As you already added the axis labels you can define a `node` and add the text inside `{}` at the end. Is this what you were asking for? Otherwise, could you specify your problem/question?

Comment: Sure, sorry if my question felt a bit ambiguous. I don't want to add text inside the graph, rather I want to add alt text when hovering over the image.
So, if a screen reader encounters this it would read something like "A graph in a plane with a point at ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a graph is large, it is better to set a certain icon (here red `\Homer`) to hover over to get the text.  If you standardize the icon throughout the presentation, the reader can quickly get the gist.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdfcomment,tikz,simpsons}
\begin{document}
\pdftooltip{\textcolor{red}{\Homer}}{A graph in a plane with a point at ...}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);
    \fill[black] (origo) circle (0.05);
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(3,0) node(mary)[black,right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,3) node[black,right] {$y$};
    \draw[thick] (origo) -- ++(45:3) coordinate (bob);
    \fill (bob) circle (0.05);
    \node[] at (1.2,1.5){r};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can go further and inset him in the graph:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdfcomment,tikz,simpsons,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{10pt}{b}{20pt}
{\pdftooltip{\textcolor{red}{\reflectbox{\Homer}}}
  {A graph in a plane with a point at ...}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);
    \fill[black] (origo) circle (0.05);
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(3,0) node(mary)[black,right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,3) node[black,right] {$y$};
    \draw[thick] (origo) -- ++(45:3) coordinate (bob);
    \fill (bob) circle (0.05);
    \node[] at (1.2,1.5){r};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great fix, thanks!

Comment: @JamesRhyder I extended my answer to show how to inset him anywhere inside the graph, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can just add the tool tips in nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(3,0) node(mary)[black,right] 
    {\pdftooltip{$x$}{horizontal coordinate}};
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,3) node[black,right] 
    {\pdftooltip{$y$}{vertical coordinate}};
    \draw[thick] (origo) --node[anchor=-45]{\pdftooltip{$r$}{radius}} ++(45:3) coordinate (bob);
    \fill[black] (origo) circle[radius=0.05] (bob) circle[radius=0.05];
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]