Tagging Graphics
First: This is somewhat a follow-up question to Tagging of Included Graphics (because I forgot to ask the following in the other question :-().
I (now) know how to use the alt key to give a proper written description of externally inserted graphics in a LaTeX document, but what if I have a PSTricks drawing?
My first thought was to somehow put an 'empty' image inside the drawing using \includegraphics and then use the alt key to give a proper description of the drawing. However, this approach doesn't seem right at all.
P.S. I use LuaLaTeX for all my documents these days.

For TikZ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591976/adding-alt-text-to-a-tikz-graph recommends a \pdftooltip, that may work with PSTricks as well.

I think that you use alt attribute then ask that it gets supported somewhere.... use of alt on things other than bitmap isn't well supported by pdf viewers (there is an issue somewhere with alt not working in acrobat on \includegraphics{foo.pdf)

@DavidCarlisle So just to be clear: I can't tag a PSTricks drawing (at present)?

@DavidCarlisle If I can't, I'll probably create a 1x1 pixel empty .eps picture that I can insert and then use the alt key. I know that it is very 'ugly' but I guess it works. :-)

I think not automatically at present although you could use lower level commands from tagpdf package to add a tagged region around it (or rather, I expect Ulrike could do that:-)

As listed here https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/ pstricks is currently incompatible. To make it compatible one would have to enhance the environment to add an optional argument, and to store the Bbox similar to the changes I made for the picture environment. Ask the maintainer if he is willing to do that ... (I would help him)

@UlrikeFischer Herbert Voß has given it a "maybe" that it will be done in the near future.

Something like this???   Needs lualatex --shell-escape ...
\begin{document}

\begin{externalDocument}[
    compiler=lualatex,
    crop,
    code=false,
    grfOptions={alt=my wonderful image}]{exa}
\DocumentMetadata{} 
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[x,-90][y,0]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{externalDocument}

\end{document}


That adds pdf comments but not structure tags.

Thanks for your answer, but as Ulrike says, it isn't quite what I'm after. I've written an e-mail to the PSTricks package maintainer and asked for a "proper" solution, as suggested by Ulrike in the comment above.
